# An Idiom/phrase/adjective for an imaginary place where everything is perfect

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms, adjectives

> A place where unrealistic and impossible things can happen.

Is there an idiom/expression/phrase that connotes to such a stretch of the imagination?

Comment: Literature and religions are full of examples including Fantasyland, Utopia, Nirvana, Camelot, Never-Neverland, to name a few. (Oh yeah, and Heaven!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for **utopia**.

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Autopia&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) defines it as:

> an imagined place or state of things in which everything is perfect. The word was first used in the book Utopia (1516) by Sir Thomas More.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/utopia) says it is often capitalized as Utopia and defines it as:

> an imaginary place in which the government, laws, and social conditions are perfect
>
> often capitalized :  a place of ideal perfection especially in laws, government, and social conditions

Answer (score 0):

Probably [wonderland](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wonderland) may suggest the place you are looking for:

> - a place or scene of great or strange beauty or wonder

or [dreamworld](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Dreamworld):

> - a pleasing country existing only in dreams or imagination; a fantasy land.

Answer (score 0):

**Shangri-La** is one of these places

> Shangri-La is a fictional place described in the 1933 novel Lost Horizon by British author James Hilton. Hilton describes Shangri-La as a mystical, harmonious valley, gently guided from a lamasery, enclosed in the western end of the Kunlun Mountains. **Shangri-La has become synonymous with any earthly paradise**, and particularly a mythical Himalayan utopia – a permanently happy land, isolated from the outside world. [Wikipédia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shangri-La)